# How to get the class of an individual using Jena?

Tags: jena

I have a class Joy in my ontology. It has individuals Happy, Glad etc. The isDefinedBy Annotation property of Happy states Joy. Now I wanted to get the class name (or URI) for any individual passed, so I tried getOntClass() method for the individual, but didn't get the required result. Then I tried getIsDefinedBy() method and got this.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ConversionException: Cannot convert node "Joy" to OntResource
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl$1.wrap(OntResourceImpl.java:79)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:152)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:31)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.Polymorphic.asInternal(Polymorphic.java:62)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.as(EnhNode.java:107)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl.objectAs(OntResourceImpl.java:1411)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl.objectAsResource(OntResourceImpl.java:1421)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntResourceImpl.getIsDefinedBy(OntResourceImpl.java:395)
at myPackage.Ontology.load(Ontology.java:90)
at myPackage.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:75)
```

Here's the code I used

```
Individual indiv = mod.getIndividual(namespace + "Happy");
//System.out.println(indiv.getOntClass());
System.out.println(indiv.getIsDefinedBy());
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know of Jena (I've been working with it for 3 months now) you are misunderstanding the meaning of URI. URI stands for Unique Resource Identificator or something similar, so that 2 individuals of the same OntClass would have different URIs but the same OntClass.

Correct me if I'm wrong but you want to get this OntClass the individuals belong to, right? 
If it is the OntClass you want to retrieve my personal solution to the matter was to use the property `type` of the `rdf` namespace.

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntModel();
m.read("file:///" + ontologyPath);
string RDF = m.getNsPrefixURI("rdf");
string namespace = m.getNSPrefixURI(yourOntologyPrefix);
Property type = m.getProperty(RDF, "type");
Individiual indiv = m.getIndividual(namespace + "Happy");
if (indiv.getPropertyResourceValue(type).toString().Equals(namespace + "Joy"))
    println("you got it");
else
    println("this is not joy :(");
```

May not be the most elegant way to do it but well :D

Comment: Yes, I guess I'm misunderstanding & perhaps getting confused between different concepts in Jena. I was looking for how to get the type property, because when I created the ontology in Protege, I defined type for each individual; so thank you for that. :)

The result is still incorrect. In terms of your code, I get "this is not joy :("

One other thing is that the application won't know the class name in advance. It has to get the class for any individual which is passed.

Comment: In simple words, how can I retrieve the class of any individual?

I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Oh I got it...!
Here's what I did.
`String RDFS = mod.getNsPrefixURI("rdfs");`
`Property comment = mod.getProperty(RDFS, "comment");`
`Individual indiv = mod.getIndividual(namespace + "Happy");`
`System.out.println(indiv.getProperty(comment).getSeq());`

...And the result : "Joy" :D

Oh, I added Joy in comment of Happy in Protege before doing above of course.
Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Oh  right, you did say it was a comment (a type of annotation) so the namespace was `rdfs` and not `rdf`. You're welcome! I know Jena can be tricky sometimes with terms :d

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (which I am using right now) is the following code:

```
List<OntClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
ExtendedIterator<Resource> it = individual.listRDFTypes(true);
while (it.hasNext()) {
   Resource res = it.next();
   try {
      OntClass theClass = res.as(OntClass.class);
      list.add(theClass);
   } catch (ConversionException e) {
      // this can happen if the Resource is not a Class
   }
}
```

I found this by looking in the Jena source. Note that an Individual may correspond to more than one Class. The `individual.listRDFTypes(true)` code will consider only the individual as a direct child of the Class, but if you do `individual.listRDFTypes(false)` it will also consider children of subclasses.